# Action Bar is in ''grey"/invisible color

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to create an options menu for my activity.
First off, it doesn't show, I followed instruction and I added the requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR); in the onCreate method and the action bar is showing but it is in 'grey'/invisible color. I still can click on an menu item. Could you please tell me how to make the action bar visible? Thanks.
Here is my Activity, is extending FragmentActivity which is a must because I need it for my map fragment:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity{
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

}

And here is my style, the manifest is using the FMSTheme below:

```
<!-- FMS theme -->
<style name="FMSTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">false</item>
</style>
```

[Invisible actionbar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2M5y.png)

Comment: What is you colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your MapsActivity to extend AppCompatActivity (from the support library) which itself extends a FragmentActivity:

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

Once you've done so, I would recommend to set a Toolbar as an actionbar:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.maps_activity_toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("A title");
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

You can then configure your Toolbar's themes using these 2 properties:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:theme="@style/MyToolbarTheme"
    app:popupTheme="@style/MyToolbarPopupTheme">
```

which you can customize at your wish, for instance you could have a dark action bar theme with a light menu theme (or viceversa):

```
<!-- the theme of the toolbar on MapsActivity -->
<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <!-- default text color and menu dots -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/my_toolbar_text_color</item>
</style>

<!-- the theme of the menu which opens from ActionBar on MapsActivity -->
<style name="MyToolbarPopupTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Alessio, changing the extends to AppCompatActivity works, the menu bar is visible now. And thanks a lot for Toolbar customization...

Comment: You're more than welcome @M.N, Toolbar is your friend here, and such a powerful tool, more flexible than ActionBar :)